# Search multidimensional php array by key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional php array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => M
            [colour] => black
            [quantity] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [size] => S
            [colour] => blue
            [quantity] => 10
        )

)
```

and i have another array like this

```
Array
(
    [size] => M
    [colour] => black
)
```

How do i transverse to first array to find the array that matches the second one?.
Am totally clueless on how to go about this. Thanks

Comment: try to solve the problem in the query and not with PHP. A simple `where` would do!

Comment: just to clarify what @JvdBerg said, what you should do is if you're trying to find all records containing size=M and color=black, you should probably do this in your SQL query if you are pulling this data from the database. it's more efficient rather than pulling out all information from the database and searching it using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first array is "mainarray" and second one is "comparearray"

```
$result = array();
    foreach($mainarray as $marray)
    {
      if($marray['size'] == $comparearray['size'] && $marray['colour'] == $comparearray['colour'])
    {
       $result = $marray;
    //echo "match found";
    }
    }
```

note: if compare array is single array it is applicable. if that also multidimension array you should put foreach for that array also.

Comment: Your snippet works, but would it be possible to return the matching array?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a different approach:

```
$multiArray = array(array('size'     => 'M', 
                          'color'    => 'black',
                          'quantity' => '10'), 
                    array('size'     => 'S', 
                          'color'    => 'blue',
                          'quantity' => 10));

$otherArray = array('size'     => 'S', 
                    'color'    => 'blue',
                    'quantity' => 10)

$message = "Match not found!";

foreach($multiArray as $array) {
    $result = array_diff($array, $otherArray);

    if(isset($result['size']) or isset($result['color'))
        continue;
    else
        $message = "Found a match!\n Size: {$array['size']}\n Color: {$array['color']}\n Quantity: {$array['quantity']}"; 
}
echo $message;
```

This solution seems correct to me because from your example I'm guessing you are trying to find the quantity. Therefore, the array_diff will return the quantity in the result regardless, resulting in the need to check for just size and color for a match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(array("size"=>"M","colour" => "black"),array("size"=>"S","colour" => "blue"));
$arr2 = array("size"=>"M","colour" => "black");
print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $array)
{
  if($array['size'] == $arr2['size'] && $array['colour'] == $arr2['colour'])
  {
      echo "matches";
  }
}
?>
```

working example http://codepad.org/iQPxSHKd

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = array();
foreach ($multi_array as $arr) {
  if ($arr['size'] == $one_dimen_arr['size'] && $arr['colour'] == $one_dimen_arr['colour']) {
    $result = $arr;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

$array1 is your First array and $array2 is your Second array. Then :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $subarray)
{
    $check = array_diff($subarray, $array2);
    if (empty($check)) {
        $result = $subarray;
    }
}
```